# Can we force new and low rep users to actually read the "How to Ask" page?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Seriously, I'm tired of having to write [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788946/wpf-c-sharp-event-handler-which-ive-added-to-the-button-in-mainwindow-does#comment38472528_24788946) for every single question from a new user.

Maybe force disable the "ask question" button until the user has scrolled down the page, like some "License Agreement" screens for some apps do?

Comment: Force them? What would that achieve?

Comment: It would achieve that they actually read the stuff? - otherwise what do you want that page for (the "How to Ask" one) if no one cares about it, because new users don't read and experienced users already know how to create good quality questions?

Comment: So how many licence agreements have you read through as a result of them not enabling the "agree" button until you've scrolled to the bottom?  Or just how many licence agreements have you read ever, let's start with that.

Comment: We could hijack their microphone and record how they read it out loud  or we could make a multiple choice test on it...

Comment: @Trilarion that's a good one. I vote for the microphone thing

Comment: And? Assuming they read it, you think that would change anything? And that they wouldn't simply try to "game" the system? We already show brand new users a page, require them to fill a checkbox and click an "I agree" button (well, something to that effect).

Comment: @Servy license agreements are irrelevant to me because I live in a country where 99% of the software is pirated.

Comment: @HighCore And you think "how to ask" is going to seem relevant to someone who just wants to ask their programming question?  People that are going to read it already do.  The people that don't won't just because you make this change.  They'll just hate you all the more for trying to get them to read something they know they have no interest in reading.  And if you think people who *aren't* pirating their software read those agreements any more, they don't.

Comment: @Oded I didn't know that.

Comment: @Servy other than that, can we add a **POST your FREAKING CODE** message in the asking page?

Comment: @Oded other than that, can we add some kind of advice explaining that asking "is this possible?" doesn't make any sense and make it clear that questions asking "why doesn't this work?" or "how to make this work?" SHOULD include relevant code? I mean in the asking page itself, and not somewhere else where people won't read it.

Comment: @HighCore: At best, that will result in a deluge of tangentially-related code. You want an MCVE.

Comment: [**No**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208687/close-vote-queue-reduction-add-click-to-ask-question), that's impossible.

Comment: LOL. I love the downvotes. Luckily I don't get any rep decrease about it.

Comment: @HighCore What's actually wrong for you with the links given in the [on hold] messages of closed questions? I believe a user experiencing this a few times **will** read sooner or later what's provided there.

Comment: I find it interesting that a programmer that considers software license agreements to be irrelevant to him is asking this question...

Comment: I actually think that this would be a good idea if there was a way to enforce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is really no way to force someone to read a page without actually being there sitting beside them.  In your proposed solution, they can just scroll down and be done with it.  If they really don't care, they will always find a way out of it.

Putting that aside, even after reading it, they will probably just ignore it and do what they want.  If someone is in a big hurry, their first thought is probably not "Wow, I should seriously research this question instead of having someone experienced do it for me."

It is already beside the Ask Question page so that users who actually want to improve their questions can learn how.

Comment: Actually you can make tests (waiting for scrolling down is ineffective) that work, for example with old school multiple choice, but who wants that? We would bother nice users too and downvoting the first question of someone is far easier too.

Comment: Yea, but still, knowing how to do it and actually doing it are two completely different things.

Comment: MC would be super-easy to create: SO is A) discussion forum B) Wiki C) Q&A site. on SO you ask about A) whatever you want, B) specific programming question, C) everything related to computers. ...

Answer (score 4):

The exact thing you describe has existed for years. Create a new account, and try to ask a question...

Comment: I'm happy it does and that it has for years, but did it exist in mid-2014 when this question was posed?

Comment: Yes, @makoto. AFK, but I believe this was introduced in 2011, maybe before. Kinda bummed no one ever pointed this out.

Comment: @Shog9 The question was asking for that step to be even more obnoxious than it is; requiring the user to open the page, and scroll all the way to the bottom, rather than just having a link and a button to say you read it (which basically everyone is going to click without reading).

Comment: This is the page I'm talking about, @servy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice (it behaves a bit differently if you're a new user, but in either case to progress to /questions/ask you need to go to the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a possible solution would be, for users with low ratings, to add text to the top of the page where they ask a question, that lists the basic requirements of a good question, and perhaps also a pop-up dialog that reminds them to read that information.

If a user isn't prepared to spend a few minutes asking a question properly - do we want them here wasting out time flagging questions that are off-topic or too broad that are driving us to start posting non-constructive and sarcastic comments (which incidentally don't help new users' opinion of the site)?

Comment: This is already done, and has been done for a long, long time.

Comment: @Servy ah ok - I seem to have forgotten that this happened - I am old you know - Nearly 50 ;-)

Comment: This happened many years before you joined the site.